# Complex SELECT MySQL statement

Tags: php, mysql

I have run into an issue selecting data from my MySQL database.

For example, I have a table with the following columns & tables:

```
Table name: farming

id | animal | amount | food
----------------------------
1  |   Cow  |    10  | Grass
12 |  Sheep |    19  | Grass
23 |  Lion  |     1  | Everything
29 |  Lamb  |     3  | Grass
102|   Pig  |     8  | Everything
...
```

I want to get the `amount` from all the rows that match the `food` type of a selected `id`.

E.g. If I choose `id: 102` then it would get the `amount` from ALL rows where the `food = 'Everything'`

`SELECT amount FROM farming WHERE food = '".$_GET['food']."' **IS THE SAME TYPE AS IT IS IN** id = '1'";` // This should select `10`, `19` and `3` from `amount` (as `id = 1`'s foodtype is `Grass`, so it should select `amount` from all rows where  foodtype = grass.

**  is where I'm facing issues, I've tried various statements and can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: Use nested query `SELECT amount FROM farming WHERE food = (select food from farming where id = 102)`

Comment: @gvmani That solved it! Nice one!

Answer (score 0):

You could use group by clause which will sum up all value from amount column whre food = 'Grass'

```
SELECT SUM(amount) ammount FROM farming 
      WHERE food = (select food FROM farming where id = 102) 
      GROUP BY food
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
select  amount
from    farming
where   food = (
            select  food
            from    farming
            where   id = 1
        )
```